# Examples of popular, commercial applications written in PHP?

Tags: php

I was just curious to see if I could get together a list of some popular, commercial applications written with the PHP language. I'm just curious what people have built using PHP and how well it seems to fit the application they've developed.

Some I know of are:

1. ModernBill
2. WHMCS
3. vBulletin

What else is out there?

**EDIT:** To clarify, I'm looking for resalable commercial applications you can purchase. i.e. think "I purchased a copy of Microsoft Windows" not "I used the Google search engine."

Comment: Polls should be Community Wiki.

Comment: This isn't a poll... read the question.

Comment: There still is no definitive *correct* answer. It's a »Hey guys, what's out there?« type of question which should be CW.

Comment: Ah, OK, well that makes more sense then. If I had any idea how to move it, I could do that...

Comment: click "edit" under your question and tick "community wiki"&save

Comment: **Before you answer:** Look through all the current answers and check for duplicates (if found, improve them, it is CW).  If it's worth your time answering, do you want to create the dupe-fest that hides the useful information in so many other questions?

Answer (score 19):

How about Facebook? I hear that's popular these days.

Comment: PHP really just provides the html views for facebook. The majority of the backend is not PHP. But it does show that PHP can be relied upon, its not faulty, just not usable for "everything"

Answer (score 8):

Digg.com and Wordpress would both be a pretty large players.

Answer (score 6):

[Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/) - an eCommerce package

Answer (score 4):

[ExpressionEngine](http://expressionengine.com/) is written in PHP, pretty popular blogging engine.

Edit:
Oh, and don't forget the site-tracker [Mint](http://haveamint.com/) and the RSS-reader [Fever](http://feedafever.com/).

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP):

> As of April 2007, over 20 million
>   Internet domains had web services
>   hosted on servers with PHP
>   installed and mod_php was recorded as
>   the most popular Apache HTTP
>   Server module. Significant websites are
>   written in PHP including the
>   user-facing portion of Facebook,
>   Wikipedia (MediaWiki), Yahoo!,
>   MyYearbook, Digg, Joomla, WordPress,
>   YouTube in its early stages,
>   Drupal, Tagged and Moodle.

Answer (score 1):

Timely find I made here:

10 years of PHP Applications that changed the world

http://blog.fedecarg.com/2008/05/22/open-source-php-applications-that-changed-the-world/

Did you mean not-open-source or did you mean money-making companies?

Answer (score 1):

I really like [activeCollab](http://www.activecollab.com/). It's a project management and collaboration tool.

Answer (score 1):

Good examples of commercial php software I'm aware of are (not in order): activecollab, vivvo cms, predator cms, interspire email marketer... but there are also many small scripts that sells well on codecanyion as far as I can see their sales statistics

Answer (score 0):

Not really a commercial app but Facebook is PHP based.  If you are concerned about the load and ability to support many users I think that is a good example.

Comment: How is Facebook not commercial????????

Comment: I think commercial = an app you can purchase.

Comment: Yeah, I heard everyone at facebook works for free, its more of a movement than a company.

Comment: Ya, and ad space is free as well

Comment: I like how my suggestion was obliterated with comments yet the top answer is Facebook.

Answer (score 0):

[Cube cart](http://www.cubecart.com/) is another one.